# Using a test suite, how can I get the tests to show up in the "Tests" pane view for Qt5?

Tags: c++, qt5, qtest

I have setup a TestSuite in Qt5 basically following the instructions from [here](https://asmaloney.com/2017/01/code/code-coverage-of-unit-tests-using-qt-5-on-macos/) and [here](https://alexhuszagh.github.io/2016/using-qttest-effectively/). It works as described; however; when I switch from the **Projects** view to **Tests** view it does **NOT** show the individual class tests as shown in the TestsView image below. I expect it to show my test class and the individual function slots. This is useful for when I am debugging or I would only like to execute a single test function in the test class.

Workaround solution I found:
In main.cpp, if I instantiate the class and call qExec() instead of using a QOject* to the test class instance then it works (show in main.cpp below); however, this defeats the purpose of the test suite class.

[image: Tests View]

```cpp
// testsuite.h
#pragma once

// Qt headers
#include <QObject>
#include <QtTest/QtTest>

class TestSuite : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit TestSuite();
    virtual ~TestSuite();

    static QVector<QObject*>& suite();
};
```

```cpp
// testsuite.cpp
#include "testsuite.h"

#include <QDebug>

TestSuite::TestSuite()
{
    suite().push_back(this);
}

TestSuite::~TestSuite() {}

QVector<QObject*>& TestSuite::suite()
{
    static QVector<QObject*> instance;
    return instance;
}
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "testsuite.h"

#include <QtTest>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Q_UNUSED(argc)
    Q_UNUSED(argv)

    int failedTestsCount = 0;

    for (auto &test : TestSuite::suite()) {
        int result = QTest::qExec(test);
        if (result != 0) {
            failedTestsCount++;
        }
    }

    // Work around w/ #include class file
    //TestExampleClass testExampleClass ;
    //QTest::qExec(&testExampleClass );

    return failedTestsCount;
}
```

```cpp
// testexampleclass.h
#include <QtTest/QtTest>

#include "testsuite.h" 

class TestExampleClass : public TestSuite
{
      Q_OBJECT

   private slots:
      void  test_addSomeStuff();
};
```

```cpp
// testexampleclass.cpp
#include "testexampleclass.h"

static TestExampleClass  sInstance;

// test adding list of numbers
void  TestExampleClass::test_addSomeStuff()
{
   QVERIFY( true );
}
```

Edit: I am using Qt Creator 4.1.2 and Qt 5.13.2 (MSVC 2017)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
During a 'Rescan Sests' the QC searches for following entries:
{"QTEST_MAIN", "QTEST_APPLESS_MAIN", "QTEST_GUILESS_MAIN"}
The following dummy macro code helped:

```
#ifdef QTEST_MAIN
#undef QTEST_MAIN
#endif
#define QTEST_MAIN(TestObject)
```

Than you have o place a `QTEST_MAIN(TestClassName)` into your test class declaration. Afterwards my tests were visible in the Treeview:
[Qt Creator Tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2HY1.png)

However QTEST_MAIN wont work anymore.